# Break a Closure

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, closures

I'm working on a small lib/script that will search the document body for `<div src="..."></div>`, retrieve content from the specified src(using XHR) and insert the content into the div. Before I go any further, let me give you an exert from the coding:

```
function Include(ele) {
    this.ele = ele;
    this.xhr = new XHR();
    this.xhr.onload = (function(incObj){
        return function(){
            incObj.onload.call(incObj,this);
        }
    })(this);
    this.xhr.open("GET",ele.getAttribute("src"),false);
    this.xhr.send();
}

Include.prototype.XHR = function(){/* code to find a viable xhr object*/}
Include.prototype.onload = function(){/* stuff */}

var inc = new Include(document.getElementById("someId"));
```

After each XHR request takes place and the content is processed, due to the closure, the xhr object isn't destroyed, causing the created Include object not to be destoryed. Which in turn, is a memory leak. It's not such a big deal for either a: Few Include requests, b: Little content from such requests but as the includes increase and the response content increases you can steadily see the memory usage increases. How would I go about breaking the closure(or using a viable work around that doesn't depend on using a global variable,obj,etc) to fix this leak?

(Please do not suggest the use of a library, even though what I'm working on is for browser js, my question applies more to how javascript itself works)

Comment: Won't incObj.onload be undefined anyway? Wouldn't it be incObj.ele.onload.call ?

Comment: Oops, guess i need to clarify that(Edited post). what I meant originally by "incObj" was the created Include Object. And no, it would be incObj.onload.call(), I want the prototype to handle the event before I pass it along to the element's event handler(s).

Comment: what's wrong with delete this.xhr ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum 'delete' doesn't actually delete members. It marks them as 'undefined' for the garbage collector. The problem here is, while the closure exists, the garbage collector won't free the memory. Basically leaving the xhr in memory but making it unaccessible

Comment: @AlanFoster as far as `incObj.onload`, when it's called and discovered to be undefined incObj's prototype will be checked for an `onload` function. If present that function will be called and if not(after a bit of prototype-chain climbing) an error would be thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
this.xhr.onload = (function(incObj){
    return function(){
        incObj.onload.call(incObj,this);
        incObj.xhr.onload = null;
    }
})(this);
```

If you have any other event handlers going on, you should dispose them as well when you don't need the object anymore.

Comment: I haven't tested yet, but wouldn't that just set the return'ed function to null while keeping the closure intact?

Comment: @SReject it would just remove the reference to the closure. If you have no other references to the closure, it should eventually be garbage collected.

Comment: Ok, thank you. will test, if it works, Ill upvote and select your answer